# b-table from BootstrapVue: responsive while fitting width to content

Tags: responsive, bootstrap-vue

How can the **width** of a *BootstrapVue* `b-table` fit to its content while being **responsive** at the same time?

---

I've tried combining the class `w-auto` with the table styling `responsive`. As soon as I use the latter, the `w-auto` is overruled. 
Having a responsive table is practical, because the fact of having a scrollbar when the table size exceeds the size of its container. But when that it is not the case, I would like the table being not bigger than its content.

---

[Here](https://codepen.io/rubebop/pen/XWaGdpV) is an example in *codepen.io*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `responsive` prop, a wrapper `<div>` is added around the `<table>`. This means that when you use `class` it will be added to that wrapper `<div>` instead of the table itself.

To add the class `w-auto` to the `<table>`, you should use the `table-class` prop instead.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { age: 40, first_name: "Dickerson", last_name: "Macdonald" },
        { age: 21, first_name: "Larsen", last_name: "Shaw" },
        { age: 89, first_name: "Geneva", last_name: "Wilson" },
        { age: 38, first_name: "Jami", last_name: "Carney" }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-table striped hover responsive table-class="w-auto" :items="items"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. I can't thank you enough for your amazing answer.